# What is the most efficient way to join two instances of ByteArray?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I want to join two instance of ByteArray in Squeak, Cuis or Pharo Smalltalk

```
b := #[10 11 12 13] asOrderedCollection.
b addAll: #[21 22 23 24].
b asByteArray
```

Are there more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: You don't define `efficient`. I'm going to assume you mean `fast` rather than `expressive` or `understandable` or `refactorable`. So it interests me that neither of the proposed answers actually show any timing results vs what you proposed. Smalltalk's an interesting language, and it's virtual machines even funkier at times. Having given a tutorial on this very subject (a couple of years ago), one of the main points, repeated over and over and over and over again if you're worried about speed is measure, measure, measure. Never assume, and recheck your assumptions all the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would concatenation be better...?

```
#[10 11 12 13],#[21 22 23 24 ]
```

Comment: concatenation calls  `, otherCollection 
 "Concatenate two Strings or Collections."
 
 ^ self copyReplaceFrom: self size + 1
    to: self size
    with: otherCollectioncode`

Comment: #copyReplaceFrom:to:with: calls #replaceFrom:to:with:startingAt: . It seems that this in fact what Colin Putney proposes, right?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Using an OrderedCollection will involve several unnecessary object allocations and redundant copying. You should create a new byte array and copy the contents of your source arrays into it:

```
a := #[10 11 12 13].
b := #[21 22 23 24].
c := ByteArray new: (a size + b size).
c replaceFrom: 1 to: a size with: a startingAt: 1.
c replaceFrom: a size + 1 to: c size with: b startingAt: 1.
```

This only allocates the new ByteArray and does the copying with primitives, so it's quite fast. It'll work in Squeak, Cuis and Pharo, and very likely other Smalltalks as well.

Comment: While your solution is definitely valid, it is overly complicated. Concatenation using #, will do the job

Comment: This answer is as well useful for me because it directly calls the #replaceFrom:to:with:startingAt: method which is implemented as a primitive. So it is easy to see that this is efficient.